# MySQL REGEX with prepared statement: "?" being misunderstood

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've consulted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850205/php-mysql-regexp-prepared-statement) for this problem, but couldn't seem to see the answer.

I have a prepared statement with a `?` placeholder for a param I'm binding. Problem is, MySQL doesn't seem to like this because it's inside a REGEX block, like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM teams WHERE name REGEXP "^(?)"';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', implode('|', $letters));
```

This throws:

```
"Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"
```

Is there a way of escaping the `?` or something?

[EDIT]

Based on the comment below, I tried:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM teams WHERE name REGEXP "^(:letters)"';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(':letters', implode('|', $letters));
```

Now I get the error

```
"Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables"
```

Interestingly, I note I'm using `bind_param()` but the [PHP docs say](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) `bindParam()`. For me, the latter is an undefined method.

Comment: can you tell me what this regex expression for?

Comment: Isn't `WHERE substr(name,0,1) IN (?)` better here?

Comment: re: `bind_param` vs. `bindParam` - that's because the former is [`mysqli`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) syntax and the latter is pdo syntax, and you are using the former. 2 diff db extensions/objects